# usage of "in other words"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I have read the following sentence in a 5 score independent writing TOEFL test.

"After stating that everyone’s opinion can be different about this, for me honesty,
in other words, always telling the truth is the most important consideration in a relationship."

the usage of "in other words" is kind of loose and feels wrong to me.

Comment: https://youtu.be/oCW9Hey6IVY

Comment: Doesn't sound wrong to me (a native American English speaker), although there really ought to be comma between "truth" and "is".

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for certain because the sentence itself is a bit confusing both in word choice/order and in punctuation. I imagine that the writer intended to indicate:

> After stating that everyone's opinion can be different about this, for me honesty - in other words, always telling the truth - is the most important consideration in a relationship.

That's more parentheticals than I personally would care to use in a sentence like this. But the phrase "in other words" would not be inappropriate if my interpretation is accurate. It clarifies the intended, specific usage of the word "honesty" in the context of the sentence.

The writing would be improved by breaking some of these clauses into separate sentences, but that's off topic with respect to the phrase itself.

Comment: I think I would employ a pair of em dashes, as follows: "After stating that everyone's opinion can be different about this, for me honesty - in other words, always telling the truth -  is the most important consideration in a relationship." However the first ten words really belong to a different sentence. I'm not at all clear what to make of them.

Comment: I think that the first clause is essentially "While conceding that opinions differ on the topic", or something similar. I like the em dashes, though I'm as hesitant to use those as I am semicolons (both are addictive). It helps make the clauses more distinct, which really helps clarify the reading.

Comment: Yep, the punctuation sucks.